# Open web page after safari extension has been installed

Tags: safari, installation, safari-extension

I've built a safari extension. Once a user has downloaded and installed it I want to open a new web page, is there perhaps an event which is fired once the installation has completed?

Comment: hey Wlad, did you find anything?

Comment: I couldn't figure it out either :/